# how can i avoid duplicate data in my data base

Tags: python, database, mongodb, data-mining

I have a script python and each time i run it the data duplicate in my db

here is my code : (here my example is attributing for each element in my collection " " for just trying if i have to information who are the same i'm  i going to find only one or i will have many even if the same

code :

```
import pymongo

def Create_DB():

        myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
        db = myclient['Le_Monde_DB']

        #la collection Corpus
        Corpus = db.Corpus
        Corpus_data = {
        'Corpus_Name': '',
        'Comment': '',

        }
        result = Corpus.update(Corpus_data,{upsert:true})
        print('One Corpus: {0}'.format(result))

        #la collection Publication 
        Publ = db.Publ
        Publ_data = {
        'Publ_Nature': '',
        }
        result = Publ.insert(Publ_data)
        print('One Publ: {0}'.format(result))


        #la collection text 
        Text = db.Text
        Text_data = {
        'Text': '',
        }
        result = Text.insert(Text_data)
        print('One Text: {0}'.format(result))


        #la collection phrase 
        Phrase = db.Phrase
        Phrase_data = {
        'Type_Phrase': '',
        'Phrase':"" 
        }
        result = Phrase.insert(Phrase_data)
        print('One Phrase: {0}'.format(result))


        #la collection Token
        Token = db.Token
        Token_data = {
        'Type_Token': '',
        'Token':"" 
        }
        result = Token.insert(Phrase_data)
        print('One Token: {0}'.format(result))

        #la collection Meta_Data
        Meta = db.Meta
        Meta_data = {
        'Type_Meta': '',
        'Value_Meta':"" 
        }
        result = Meta.insert(Meta_data)
        print('One Meta: {0}'.format(result))







Create_DB()
```

thanks for help :)

Comment: You are inserting the same data every time.

Comment: i know i'm doing crawling from a web site i collect information and store them in my db so if i have two same information how can i avoid that they appeared two times in my db ?

Answer (score 0):

@Houacine Leila,

You can create a [unique index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/) on each of the collections where you need to maintain uniqueness for the records.

Example:

For `Corpus` collection, a unique index on the `Corpus_Name` avoid storing duplicate records.

```
db.Corpus.createIndex({"Corpus_Name":1}, {"unique":true, "background":true})
```

*Note: All existing documents must have a unique value for key `Corpus_Name` if you create a unique index on this key. You need to consider removing duplicate records manually before creating such index.*

Creating a unique index on a specific key on a collection makes sure that no duplicate records are created with the same value of key in the collection.

Comment: I tried your code but i got an error NameError: name 'Corpus_Name' is not defined  so I tried to fix it ,I modified what you wrote and I did this :
Corpus.Corpus_data.createIndex({Corpus_data: 1 }, { unique: true, sparse: true })  
I got another eroor type : 
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'   :-(

Comment: Add double quotes "Corpus_Name",  "unique" and "background". The command from the answer is expected to run from mongo shell. Use python syntax if create indexes from your application